# How to output to a view using JSON in android when retrieving SQL query

Tags: android, json

I am trying to use JSON and HTTP client to retrieve data from a table in my database. The code I have seems to be working but it is not outputting anything, but if I change something on purpose in the query the error toast outputs, so I know the code is right as no error outputs. The problem is figuring out how to get the JSON output onto my view screen.

Here is the complete HTTP code:

```
public void LoadRemote()
{

     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //http post
    try{
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://deucalion0.co.uk/getscores.php");
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         is = entity.getContent();
         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }

   //convert response to string
 try{
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                       sb.append(line + "\n");
         }
         is.close();
         result=sb.toString();
         }catch(Exception e){
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
         }
 //paring data
 int score;
 String username;
 try{
       jArray = new JSONArray(result);
       JSONObject json_data=null;
       for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
              json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
              score=json_data.getInt("score");
              username=json_data.getString("username");
          }
       }
       catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Here is my SQL query:

```
$sql=mysql_query("select score, username from highscores ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
```

You can see this working [here](http://deucalion0.co.uk/getscores.php)

I would appreciate any advice on this issue.

Thanks.

I have started again due to complications, here is the activity class as it is now:

```
public class Viewscores extends Activity{

Button scores;
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewscores);

    scores = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bViewscores);

    scores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {

            LoadRemote();
        }

    });

}


  public void LoadRemote()
    {

   String result = "";
   ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     InputStream is = null;
     try{
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new                HttpPost("http://deucalion0.co.uk/getscores.php");
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         is = entity.getContent();
         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }

BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));



    }


     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok.. here is the entire code ...

```
public class Viewscores extends Activity{

Button scores;
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewscores);

scores = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bViewscores);

scores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i=new Intent(this,lst.class);
startActivity(i);
    }

});

}
```

here is the "lst" class

```
public class lst extends ListActivity{
JSONArray jArray; 
String result = null; 
InputStream is = null; 
StringBuilder sb=null;  
String s[];

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

try{ 
URL u=new URL("http://deucalion0.co.uk/getscores.php");
URLConnection tc=u.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream())); 


String line; 

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
jArray =new JSONArray(line);
s=new String[jArray.length()];
for(int m=0;m<jArray.length();m++){
    JSONObject json_data=(JSONObject)jArray.get(m);

    s[m]=json_data.getInt("score")+" "+json_data.getString("username"); 
}
} 

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s); 
setListAdapter(adapter); 
} 

catch(JSONException e1){ 
} catch (ParseException e1) { 
e1.printStackTrace(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} 
}                   |
}                                        ---
```

This one works for sure... try this... :)

Comment: Hi Raju I am still working with your suggestion, don't worry I will accept your answer, I always accept an answer. I haven't accepted it yet because I am still having difficulty getting it to work, I didn't wasn't to ask you for more help as you have already provided me with a lot. I am getting many errors and I don't know why, I think I understand the code but I'll keep working on it today, many thanks!

Comment: ok ok... but if you get any errors let me know... so that i can also learn more.. and try helping..=]

Comment: Hi Raju thanks. I think it may just my poor understanding of the code, I have spent a lot of time on this trying to figure it out myself. What would be the best way to show you the problems I am having? I understand the first class contains a button which opens another a class, in your code it was missing some stuff, I know you were just giving me an example, I tried to get rid of the errors but I don't know how. 

Thanks!

Comment: ok.. jus paste your log cat.. so that i can see what are the errors.. and then i'll try..

Comment: I can't run the code until I fix the errors, I have managed to get the errors to two, here is an image of what they are. The first error is values is not defined and the second its asking for finally after the try.

[link](http://0902221.studentplus.abertay.ac.uk/error.png)


Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8708/discussion-between-deucalion0-and-raju)

Comment: YYYESSSS!!!!!!!! You have saved me! All this time and it's done! Thanks so much! You honestly haveno idea how much hassle you have saved me, thanks for continually helping me with this whole thing, I owe you!!!

I am about to analyse every inch of this code so I can understand why it works now!

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but isn't it easier if you create a wrapper object like this one:

```
public class Response {
        public int score;
        public String username;
    }
```

Then it's easy to deserialze the json with gson:

```
ArrayList<Response> responses = new ArrayList<Response>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Response>>(){}.getType();
responses = gson.fromJson(response, collectionType);
```

Where response is the String from the HTTP request. For more info about gson:
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't exactly understand what you mean by "get the JSON output onto my view screen"..because you have not mentioned wich views you are using.. so assuming you use listview for this ... this is what i think can be done.

```
try{
   jArray = new JSONArray(result);
   int k=jArray.length();
   String s[]=new String[k];
     for(int u=0;u<k;u++){
         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
          s[u]=json_data.getInt("score")+"  "+json_data.getString("username");
        }
           setContentView(R.layout.fine);
           ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list,R.id.textView1,s);
           lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your code example, I have spent the past three hours trying to implement it but I am getting nothing but errors, I only have a screen and a button on the screen of this activity. When I press the button I want the username and scores to display on the screen but I cannot figure out how, if I posted my whole activity class would that help you help me?


Many thanks.

Comment: 1.let me know what errors you are getting..paste your logcat. 2.yes,paste your activity class also.. so that i can try helping you.. =]

Comment: OK, thanks. By looking at what you added to my original code, it was some way of outputting the results I think? I messed around with it so much and had issues with Eclipse I had to start again, I will paste my activity class as it is just now maybe it will be easier for you to see when it is simpler anyway. I don't even know if JSON is the best way to output a query?

I will post my new code in my original post.

Thanks for your patience.